# argmin/argmax with PyOpenCL

Tags: opencl, pyopencl, argmax

How would I write argmin or argmax with PyOpenCL?  I figure I would need to calculate the argmin/min for each workgroup, and then reduce these using subsequent invocations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapt [this](https://github.com/inducer/pyopencl/blob/master/test/test_algorithm.py#L366) to collect the minimum and its location rather than just the minimum.